# Simple PHP7.0 class incorrectly serialized

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, doctrine, php-7

I am trying to serialize an array of simple objects in PHP7.0, but for some reason it's not working. Here is the `var_dump`'d array of objects:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(My\Bundle\Entity\Role)[504]
      protected 'id' => int 2
      protected 'role' => string 'ROLE_LDAP_CHECKIN_APP_ADMIN' (length=27)
  1 => 
    object(My\Bundle\Entity\Role)[506]
      protected 'id' => int 3
      protected 'role' => string 'ROLE_LDAP_CHECKIN_APP_USER' (length=26)
  2 => 
    object(My\Bundle\Entity\Role)[507]
      protected 'id' => int 1
      protected 'role' => string 'ROLE_USER' (length=9)
```

This outputs the following serialized string:

```
a:3:{i:0;r:18;i:1;r:22;i:2;r:26;}
```

If I unserialize that string, I just get the following error:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 14 of 33 bytes
```

The class implements `\Serializiable`:

```
namespace My\Bundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Role Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table( name="role" )
 *
 */
class Role implements \Serializable
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="role", unique=true, length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $role;

    /**
     * Populate the role field
     * @param string $role ROLE_FOO etc
     */
    public function __construct($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;
    }

    /**
     * Return the id field.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set the role field
     *
     * @param $role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;
    }

    /**
     * Return the role field.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Return the role field.
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->role;
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array($this->id, $this->role));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list($this->id, $this->role) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the class is being loaded.

Edit: According to http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/classes_objects/serialization.html, the `'r'` entry in the serialized string stands for 'reference', and means that the entry is just a reference / pointer to some other entry in the array or object. Clearly, references to the 18th, 22nd and 26th entries makes no sense. Is this a PHP bug?

Comment: just to check, how are you storing/retrieving the string?  Sometimes string can have null characters `\0`, which are binary, and if you i.e. copy/paste the string, it will not unserialized correctly

Comment: I'm printing the string with `var_dump`, and in the application I'm literally just calling `unserialize(serialize($array))`. I'm doing it to isolate a bug.

Comment: So how do you build the array?  That array of objects should `serialize` and `unserialize` fine, check: https://3v4l.org/P1CNp

Comment: I would wager that this is something that Doctrine or Symfony is doing, passing the role in as a reference that's not getting properly dereferenced before serialization.

Comment: I wonder if it is related to shallow copy vs deep copy.  serialize is supposed to enumerate everything though, aka deep copy, so I think it is related to references and Doctrine somehow

Comment: @AbraCadaver The array is part of a token that is created in a pretty complex process. I was trying to deserialize / serialize the array inside of the Token's `serialize` method.

Comment: I think the bug here is related to doing nested serialization and deserialization. As I mentioned above, I was doing the serialization on my array inside of another serialization function. If I collapse the serialization / deserialization into the child class it works fine. AFAIK it's not undefined behavior to use a child -> parent serialization / unserialization pattern, so it looks like this is a PHP bug.

Comment: Probably something regarding Doctrines proxy objects, are your objects actually loaded?

Comment: @ccKep Symfony and Doctrine were not the culprits. I called the exact same code outside of the nested serialization function and it worked fine.

Comment: What do you mean by nested serialization? You have parent classes that implement Serializable and call `parent::serialize`?

Comment: What I mean is that I was calling this inside of a class that had a child that was calling `parent::serialize`. I edited the answer to be more clear.

Comment: Seems fixed in 7.0.0 - 7.0.5 (and reappeared in 7.0.6) - interesting, I didn't know about this! Thanks OP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't mention this in the question write-up, but I was calling the serialization functions inside of a wrapper class' `serialize` function. In other words, a child class had a `serialize` function in which it called `parent::serialize`, and I was trying to serialize my array inside of that nested parent's `serialize` function. Though not undefined behavior, this is a known bug in PHP (yes, it sometimes actually isn't your fault). The bug is listed here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66052&edit=1

Some excerpts from the bug report:

> The current serialization format does not specify value ids and instead relies on a count from the beginning of the data. While this works fine for "standard" serialization, it breaks horribly when custom serialization (via Serializable) is thrown into the mix.

... and ...

> The effects of this bug are one of two things:
>
> - The values simply point to the wrong variables. Very hard to debug and incredibly confusing to anyone unfamiliar with the serialization format.
> - The values point to non-existent values (-1 or max +1). This causes an error which reports the byte offset into the serialized data where the error occurred.

This explains why the references in the serialized string shown in the question were broken. I have no idea how to get around this other than manually flattening all of your serialization calls, and I'm shocked it hasn't been fixed yet by the fine folks who work on PHP. Anyways, if you're seeing seemingly inexplicable error messages about byte offsets for strings / buffers that can't be right, make sure you're not doing custom nested serialization.